# Why do workouts cause your muscles to feel heavy?

Tags: human-biology, muscles, human-physiology

I know that muscle activity causes your muscles to build up lactic acid. Is this the specific reason that your muscles begin to feel heavy? How does this relate to the healing or inflammation process for muscles, or does it?

Thanks!